# Question Marks on top of Joomla website

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am building a Joomla website but it is showing "???????????" at the very top of the site inside the `<body>`.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

I looked at the template files and I found nothing like that.

The website is: http://mreale.co.uk/br/

Comment: Check the index.php file in your template folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should edit your HTML/CSS file. It's pretty easy.
Just go to your admin panel and then something like template. (Haven't used Joomla in ages)
There you should see your templatefiles. Search for this: [image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks... I have debugged it using firebug and came to the same conclusion but this code is not in the template files. I looked everywhere... any other ideas? :(

Comment: Thanks! I found the code, you were right, but was I am not a PHP dev it took me longer to understand the code would actually br in PHP.